# Ruby on rails xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, csrf-token

I am making a contact us form. When user is logged in, the form is submitted. But when there is no user logged in, it won't submit. The contact us form should be use to all.

Controller

```
Class ContactUsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    contact = Contact.new

    contact.fname = params[:fname]
    contact.lname = params[:lname]
    contact.email = params[:email]
    contact.message = params[:message]

    if contact.save
      render json: { message: "Contact us successfully sent", data: contact }, status: 200
    else
      json_data = { message: "Something went wrong! Please try again later", error: "ContactValidSaveError" }
      render json: json_data, status: 500
    end
  end
end
```

JS

```
var data = {
  fname: $("#fname").val(),
  lname: $("#lname").val(),
  email: $("#email").val(),
  message: $("#message").val()
}
$.ajax({
  url: "/contacts",
  type: "POST",
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  },
  data: data,
  error: function(result){
    alert('Error');
  },
  success: function(result){
    console.log(result);
    alert('Success');
  }
});
```

I think it was due to the CSRF token or something. Please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it throws an error with _POST http://localhost:3000/contacts 500 (Internal Server Error)_

Comment: It would be handy to see what the error is, is it a validation error?

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/contacts 500 (Internal Server Error) **xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );** this is the error

Comment: this is in my console logs, Started POST "/contacts" for ::1 at 2021-06-14 16:36:38 +0800
Processing by ContactsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"fname"=>"test", "lname"=>"test", "email"=>"", "message"=>"tes"}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms) @JoelBlum

Comment: Seems like a validation error, is email a mandatory field on your model? (check for some validation on email).

Comment: Yes, it is mandatory. And even i commented out the email field, i am still getting the error. I saw some post, I need to put **skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token** on my controller but it is still not working.

Comment: But in the error you showed me (two comments up) email is empty. So it makes sense the form won't submit and you get a validation error right? if CSRF was the problem Rails would have showed you a CSRF error

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't notice that the email params is empty. The id name of input email is wrong in the data. That is why, it is empty. Sorry, my bad.